# Analytical form for the nuclear norm of an $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices, matrix-analysis, norms

I get the follow equation in a paper. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, then $M = A^TA$ is a positive semi-definite matrix, the nuclear norm of $A$ is:

$$ \Vert A \Vert_* = \sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(M) + 2\sqrt{\det(M)}}.$$

Are there any analytical form of nuclear norm for $n \times n$ matrix like the above form? Or just for a  $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As Gro-Tsen pointed out, I had not computed the Galois group of the governing polynomial, and, in fact, my original answer was wrong.  I believe that the following answer is correct, though.**

If by 'like the above form' you mean an expression in terms of radicals of the traces of the powers of $M$, the answer is 'no' for $n>5$. Even for $n=3$ and $n=4$, when there is such an expression, it is very ugly and will almost certainly be useless for any practical purpose:

Let  $p_i = \mathrm{tr}(M^i)$ for $1\le i\le n$, and let $q = \|A\|_*$.  If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\ge 0$ are the eigenvalues of $M$, then $p_i = {\lambda_1}^i+\cdots+{\lambda_n}^i$ and $q = \sqrt{\lambda_1}+\cdots+\sqrt{\lambda_n}$.  The problem is to compute the Galois group of the minimal polynomial of $q$ in the field generated by the $p_i$ and determine whether it is solvable, since this will determine whether $q$ can be expressed algebraically in terms of the $p_i$ using only radicals.

To clarify things, write $\mu_i = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$, so that $q = \mu_1 + \cdots + \mu_n$ while $p_i = {\mu_1}^{2i}+\cdots+{\mu_n}^{2i}$.

Let $\mathbb{S}_n\subset\mathrm{O}(n)$ be the signed permutation group acting linearly on the span of the $\mu_i$.  Thus, $\sigma\in \mathbb{S}_n$ satisfies $\sigma(\mu_i) = \epsilon_i\,\mu_{\pi(i)}$ where $\epsilon_i=\pm1$ and $\pi$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Then $\sigma$ extends to an automorphism of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ whose fixed field is easily seen to be $\mathbb{Q}(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$.
Let $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n\subset\mathbb{S}_n$ be the abelian normal subgroup consisting of the $\sigma$ of the form $\sigma(\mu_i) = \epsilon_i\,\mu_{i}$ where $\epsilon_i=\pm1$.

Consider the polynomial
$$
f(t) = \prod_{\sigma\in(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n}\bigl(t-\sigma(q)\bigr).
$$
Then $f(q) = 0$. The $t$-degree of $f$ is $2^n$, and it is easy to see that the $t$-coefficients of $f$ lie in $\mathbb{Q}(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ (since they are symmetric polynomials in ${\mu_1}^2,\ldots,{\mu_n}^2$).  Moreover, the set $R=\{\sigma(q)\ |\ \sigma\in (\mathbb{Z}_2)^n\}$ consists of $2^n$ distinct elements, which are the roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$.  The group $\mathbb{S}_n$ acts transitively on $R$, and the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear span of $R$ contains $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$, so $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ is the splitting field of $f$.  (Hence $f$ must be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}(p_1,\ldots,p_n)[t]$.)

If $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$ that preserves the set $R$, then it must preserve its $\mathrm{Q}$-linear span and it must preserve the sum of the squares of the elements of $R$, which is clearly $2^n({\mu_1}^2 + \cdots + {\mu_n}^2)$.  From this, it is easy to see that $\alpha$ must preserve the set $\{\pm\mu_1,\ldots,\pm\mu_n\}$ and hence must belong to $\mathbb{S}_n$.  Thus, the Galois group of $f$ is  $\mathbb{S}_n$.

Since $\mathbb{S}_n/(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n$ is isomorphic to the permutation group $S_n$ and since $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^n$ is abelian, it follows that $\mathbb{S}_n$ is solvable if and only if $S_n$ is solvable.  Of course, $S_n$ is solvable if and only if $n<5$.

Comment: While this is a plausible argument, it should be made clear that this does not constitute a full proof of the nonexistence of a formula in radicals: such a proof would most likely involve computing the Galois group of the extension defined by the nuclear norm over the space of (sufficiently general) matrices, probably by monodromy considerations.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen:  You are completely right.  In fact, my claimed answer is completely wrong.  I did not compute the Galois group and I should have, because it is easy.  I will change my answer.